# What is the meaning of second value in return statement in C

Tags: c

I have following c code:

```
#define ASSERT_ACTIVE(active) do { if (!active) return errno = 6, -1; } while (0);
#define errno (*_errno())

int someCrazyFunc (bool active) {
    ASSERT_INACTIVE (active);
    ...
}
```

As far as I know a `#define` will simply place replacement text in place of the specified identifier.

I like to know:

- What does `return errno = 6, -1;` means? is that returns two values in one return statement?
- What is the meaning of replacement code `(*_errno()) = 6`

Comment: @Mysticial I agree and I hate it, but it is part of code that passed to me to debug! :'(

Comment: I think this is a most lovely construct.  Would not use it in production code because it is too difficult and out of the norms however it is quite nice.  Unless _errno() returns a bad pointer in which case it could be most embarrassing!

Comment: That said, there are better (more readable) ways to write this macro...

Comment: Note that including the trailing `;` in the definition of `ASSERT_ACTIVE` renders the `do {} while(0)` construct ineffective.

Comment: @RichardChambers, it might be a lovely construct, but as far as it does not have a productive use as you call it, I don't like it at all, it supposed to increase readability of code, but so far it reduces it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a second value - a `return` statement returns exactly one value.  In the statement:

```
return errno = 6, -1;
```

The return value is the result of the expression `errno = 6, -1`.  This is an expression using the comma operator - it is parsed as `(errno = 6), -1`, which evaluates to `-1` and assigns `6` to `errno` as a side-effect.  So this means that it's equivalent to the two statements:

```
errno = 6;
return -1;
```

Assuming that `_errno()` is a function returning a pointer - for example it has a return type of `int *` - then the expression `(*_errno()) = 6` assigns the value `6` to the object pointed to by the return value of the function.  It would be equivalent to code similar to:

```
int *p = _errno();
*p = 6;
```

`errno` is often defined like this in order to give each thread in a multi-threaded implementation its own `errno`.  The function `_errno()` in this case would return a pointer to the current thread's `errno` variable.

Answer (score 1):

That is not actually a second value to the `return` statement, it's the comma operator. What it does is to evaluate the expressions on both sides of the comma, but "return" only the value of the second expression.

So what `return errno = 6, -1;` does is evaluate the expressions `errno = 6` and `-1` separately and then give back the result of the second expression `-1`, which will then be used by `return`.